# Probability for a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I have a problem with a solution. I find it hard to understand some of the steps in the solving process. Can someone help me understand whats going on here?

"Calculate the probability P(X(1)=1, X(4)=4|X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5) for a Poisson process X(t) with arrival rate λ > 0."

Solution:
\begin{align}
     (i) \ \ P(X(1)=1, X(4)=4|X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5) \\
      \
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
    (ii) = \ \frac{P(X(1)=1, X(4)=4, X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5)}{ P(X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5)} \\
      \
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
   (iii)  = \ \frac{P(X(1)=1, X(2)−X(1) = 1, X(3)−X(2) = 1, X(4)−X(3) = 1, X(5)−X(4) = 1)}{ P(X(2)=2, X(3)−X(2) = 1, X(5)−X(3) = 2)} \\
      \
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
   (iiii)  = \ \frac{[P(X(1)=1)]^5}{P(X(2)=2)P(X(2)=1)P(X(2)=2)} \\
      \
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
     = \ \frac{[[λ^1/((1!) · e^λ)]^4}{[(2λ)2/((2!) · e^2λ)]^2} \\
      \
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
     = \ \frac{1}{4} \\
      \
    \end{align}

I don´t understand what happens between (ii)->(iii)

P(X(1)=1, X(4)=4, X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5) -> P(X(1)=1,X(2)−X(1)=1,X(3)−X(2)=1,X(4)−X(3)=1,X(5)−X(4)=1)

Is this the independent increments property? 
I don´t understand why we applying this property here.

Hope someone can explain this solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not using the independent increments property, but it's kind of a preparation to use it… let's consider a simpler example.

You want to calculate: $$P(X(1) = 1, X(2) = 3)$$ unfortunately $X(1)$ and $X(2)$ aren't independent so we cannot split this into two probabilities… but we can rewrite this a bit to get increments for which we know they are independent so we can split it!

So let's do an equivalent transformation to get an increment independent of $X(1)$ to use independence. Obviously if holds: 
$$\begin{align*} && X(2) &= 3 \\ \iff && X(2) - X(1) &= 3 - X(1)\end{align*}$$

we just removed $X(1)$ on both sides… so we get:
$$\begin{align*} &\;P(X(1) = 1, X(2) = 3) \\= &\;P(X(1) = 1, X(2) - X(1) = 3 - X(1))\end{align*}$$

But now we have the additional information given, that $X(1) = 1$ so we can replace $X(1)$ on the the far right by $1$ and get:
$$\begin{align*} = &\;P(X(1) = 1, X(2) - X(1) = 3 - 1) \\= &\;P(X(1) = 1, X(2) - X(1) = 2)\end{align*}$$

And now we have the probability of independent increments and can split this and use that $X(2) - X(1) \sim X(1)$ to get
$$\begin{align*} = &\;P(X(1) = 1)\cdot P(X(2) - X(1) = 2) \\= &\;P(X(1) = 1)\cdot P(X(1) = 2)\end{align*}$$

And nothing else was done in the step from (ii) to (iii) just 4 times more to get 5 independent increments.

So actually it's nothing else then transform a system of equations, e.g. for the nominators:

$$X(1)=1, X(4)=4, X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5$$ is equivalent to $$X(1)=1, X(2)−X(1) = 1, X(3)−X(2) = 1, X(4)−X(3) = 1, X(5)−X(4) = 1$$ and so it follows both probabilities are the same, hence
$$\begin{align*}
&\; P(X(1)=1, X(4)=4, X(2)=2, X(3)=3, X(5)=5 ) \\ =&\; P(X(1)=1, X(2)−X(1) = 1, X(3)−X(2) = 1, X(4)−X(3) = 1, X(5)−X(4) = 1)\end{align*}$$

Comment: Okay. Now I think I got this. So from step (ii)->(iii) it´s basically some rewriting. This is done so we would be able to split the probabilities up, with the independent increments property in the later steps? Many thanks for this clear explanation.

Comment: Exactly! Nothing else was done…